# XPath for input checkbox near label?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

### Screenshot

[image]

### HTML excerpt

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <i class="item_icon"/>
  <a>
    <span>timmy.txt</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to target this specific input element while using the textfile name "timmy.txt". I'm not entirely sure why `//div//a[contains(text(), "timmy.txt")]//input` does not work in this situation. Can someone please assist me with why this xpath doesn't work and also provide a solution I can use that will allow me to target this input element by using the textfile's name (ie: timmy.txt)?

Comment: Post text as text, not links to pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[contains(.,"timmy.txt")]/input
```

will select all `input` child elements of `div` elements whose string value contains a `"timmy.txt"` substring.

Comment: Just tested and it seemed to have worked! Thank you so much for the fast reply.